How can I make my Pdf (KnpSnappy) text selectable and my links clickable?
I'm currently using KnpSnappy/wkhtmltopdf to generate PDF file. Genrating the file works perfectly fine but the issue is that the text inside the PDF and  tags of the the html given in parameter are not selectable or clickable. I am not so familiar with that library so I don't know if I am missing something.
 /**
     * @Route("/sheets/{id}/export", name="export_sheet", requirements={"id"=".+"})
     * @ParamConverter("sheet", converter="public_id_converter", options={"mapping": {"id": "publicId"}})
     */
    public function exportSheet(Sheet $sheet, Request $request, PdfMerger $merger, Pdf $knpSnappyPdf, GlobalParameterRepository $globalParameterRepository, PerimeterRepository $perimeterRepository, PerimeterParameterRepository $perimeterParameterRepository, EntityManagerInterface $manager, DelegationRepository $delegationRepository, GlobalParameterRepository $gpRepo): void
    {
        if($this->getUser()->getOptions()["codeUnite"] != $sheet->getUnityCode() && !Utils::hasAccessWithDelegation($sheet->getUnityCode(), $delegationRepository)){
            throw new AccessDeniedException("Accès non autorisé - Vous n'avez pas les permissions pour visualiser cette fiche.");
        }

        // $knpSnappyPdf->setBinary('C:\DEV\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe'); # if user on windows.

        $perimeter = $perimeterRepository->findOneBy(["label" => mb_strtoupper($this->getUser()->getOptions()["perimeter"])]);

        $params = [];
        foreach ($perimeterParameterRepository->findBy(["perimeter" => $perimeter]) as $param) {
            $params[$param->getConst()] = $param->getValue();
        }

        $globals = [];
        foreach ($globalParameterRepository->findAll() as $global) {
            $globals[$global->getConst()] = $global->getValue();
        }

        /*return $this->render('sheet/export.html.twig', [
            'sheet' => $sheet,
            'pathToPublic' => '',
            'params' => $params,
            'globals' => $globals
        ]);*/
        
        $html = $this->renderView('sheet/export.html.twig', array(
            'sheet' => $sheet,
            'params' => $params,
            'globals' => $globals
        ));

        // If file is uploaded by perimeter admins. Then add it to all PDF exports.
        if (isset($params["ADDITIONAL_FILE_PDF_EXPORT"]) && $params["ADDITIONAL_FILE_PDF_EXPORT"] != null && $params["ADDITIONAL_FILE_PDF_EXPORT"] != "null"){
            // Create a new PDF Collection
            $pdfCollection = new PdfCollection();

            // add our generated PDF by creating a Setasign StreamReader from PDF string returned by KNPSnappyBundle, then add perimeter PDF file uploaded
            $pdfCollection->addPdf(StreamReader::createByString($knpSnappyPdf->getOutputFromHtml($html)));

            if ($sheet->getSelectedQuotation() != null && file_exists($this->getParameter('kernel.project_dir')."/public/uploads/sheet/selectedQuotation/".$sheet->getSelectedQuotation())){
                $pdfCollection->addPdf($this->getParameter('kernel.project_dir')."/public/uploads/sheet/selectedQuotation/".$sheet->getSelectedQuotation(), PdfFile::ALL_PAGES, PdfFile::ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
            }
            
            $pdfCollection->addPdf($this->getParameter('kernel.project_dir')."/public/uploads/".mb_strtolower($this->getUser()->getOptions()["perimeter"])."/additional_pdf_export.pdf", PdfFile::ALL_PAGES, PdfFile::ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

            // Auto download thanks to parameter PdfMerger::MODE_DOWNLOAD
            $merger->merge($pdfCollection, 'Export-'.Utils::getPublicId($sheet, "-").'.pdf', PdfMerger::MODE_DOWNLOAD, PdfFile::ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        }

Here is a short part of my function
The thing here is that I get my html from a twig template with renderView(), store it in a $html var, and then I'm generating my file with $knpSnappyPdf->getOutputFromHtml($html).

Please show the source of the class PdfCollection.
